# Maximal antichains in a forcing which adds surjections

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $P$ be a separative partial order such that $\left| P \right| \leq \left| \alpha \right|$ and 
$$\Vdash_P\exists f(f\colon\omega\to\alpha\text{ is surjective}\land f\notin\check V).$$
I want to prove that for any $p \in P$ there is a maximal antichain below p of cardinality $\left| \alpha \right|$.
In Proposition 10.20 in Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite" (p. 129) this is proved as follows:
If $\left| \alpha \right| = \omega$, this follows from $\Vdash f \notin \check V$ since any condition must have incompatible extensions. If $\left| \alpha \right| > \omega$, this follows from the collapse of $\left| \alpha \right|$ to $\omega$ and the consequent failure of the $\left| \alpha \right|-c.c$.

I see that in the case of $\left| \alpha \right| = \omega$ it is enough to prove that any condition have incompatible extensions. But how does this follows from $\Vdash f \notin \check V$? 
And how does the failure of the $\left| \alpha \right|-c.c$ follow from the collapse of $\left| \alpha \right|$ to $\omega$ in the case of $\left| \alpha \right| > \omega$? I know this is true if $\left| \alpha \right|$ is regular.

Comment: If some condition $p \in P$ has no pairwise incompatible conditions below it, then $G = \{q \in P : q \geq p \vee p \leq q\}$ meets every dense set in $V$ while $V[G] = V$ has no new sets contradicting the assumption.  By a theorem of Tarski, if $P$ has antichains of every size below a singular cardinal $\lambda$, then it also has an antichain of size $\lambda$. This implies that $P$ is not $|\alpha|$-c.c.

Comment: @hot_queen What exactly is the theorem of Tarski, that you are referring to?

Comment: I misattributed the result - It is a joint result of Erdos and Tarski http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1943-04.pdf